# Vampiric Touch + FS/FGS - Who gets the hit points from the damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting, mounted-combat

Separately from [my other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/204779/44723) about where to get the spell attack modifier value from when sharing a spell with [Find](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-steed)/[Greater Steed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-greater-steed), but similar in situation.

[Vampiric Touch](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/vampiric-touch):

> On a hit, the target takes 3d6 necrotic damage, ***and you*** regain hit points equal to half the amount of necrotic damage dealt. Until the spell ends, you can make the attack again on each of your turns as an action.

Does the mount recover HP from this attack when it delivers it, or does the caster?

Relevant Rules Text;

PHB, Page 202; Rules of Magic -> Range: "Other spells, such as the shield spell, ***affect only you***. *These spells have a range of self*."

PHB, Page 204; Rules of Magic -> Targets: "A typical spell requires you to pick one or more targets to be affected by the spell’s magic."

Vampiric Touch; Range -> Self

Valid Targets: Self. "*Affect only you.*"

Conclusion; the attack roll is a feature granted by the spell cast on yourself, with its own separate targeting function, much like the natural weapons function of Alter Self.

Alternate conclusion; Vampiric Touch (and Alter Self; natural weapons) does nothing, because creatures other than self are not a valid target for any component of the spell.

The answer to the suggested and linked question was asked separately explicitly because of the spell text saying "you regain," as opposed to "Make a melee spell attack," without being preceded by "You." There is room, I feel, for the answers to not cleave the same way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vampiric Touch while mounted on FS/FGS. What melee spell attack does my steed use?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/204779/vampiric-touch-while-mounted-on-fs-fgs-what-melee-spell-attack-does-my-steed-us)

Comment: @Trish These are clearly different questions, at least, as framed. A hypothetical "how does VT work with FGS" question could conceivably cover both questions and be a suitable dupe target, but we don't have that (and don't need it). Voting to leave open in review.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

#### *Vampiric Touch* is not an eligible spell for *Find Steed*.

*Find Steed* requires that the spell targets *only* the caster, while the text of *Vampiric Touch* specifically mentions other targets (emphasis mine):

> Make a melee spell attack against a creature within your reach. On a hit, the **target** takes 3d6 necrotic damage, [...].

The Range entry of spells description does not correspond to the target(s) of the spell. As an example, consider the [*Haste*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/haste) spell: it has  a range of 30 ft., it has only one target and the target can be the caster itself. Hence, it is a suitable spell for the *Find Steed* feature.

#### A DM can overcome this rule and decide that *Vampiric Touch* works with *Find Steed*.

Suppose that the DM rules otherwise and *Vampiric Touch* is an eligible spell for affecting also the mount, under the rules of *Find Steed*<sup>1</sup>. Then, the description of the spell implies that the attacker, who is also the caster, drains the HPs (emphases mine):

> **Make a melee spell attack** against a creature within your reach. On a hit, the target takes 3d6 necrotic damage, and **you regain** hit points equal to half the amount of necrotic damage dealt. Until the spell ends, **you can make the attack again** on each of your turns as an action.

There are two interpretations here.

- the mount is the attacker but it is not the caster: the drained HPs are absorbed by the caster, *i.e.* the mount acts as a "healing channel" for the caster for successful attacks.
- the mount is the attacker and it is considered also the caster, for the purpose of *Vampiric Touch*: the drained HPs are absorbed by the mount.

The DM has hence to adopt a ruling and decide the interaction between these two spells.

---

<sup>1</sup> See [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/204784/63061) of mine for some discussion about the eligibility of *Vampiric Touch* under *Find Steed*.

Comment: Downvoted because *vampiric touch* doesn’t work with FGS at all.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Modified accordingly to the rules, but I left there the previous discussion in case the DM wants to rule otherwise.

Comment: I have edited my question to include relevant rules text that outlines in both literal and RAW terms why the spell's targeting schema isn't all that ambiguous IMO, but also +1'd and accepted. I appreciate that you engaged the premise even if your initial assertion is that it's impossible RAW.

Answer (score 14):

#### *Vampiric Touch* cannot be shared with your steed

As on [your other recent question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/204779/28941), this whole question is based on a misapprehension: That *Vampiric Touch* is eligible for sharing with your mount. *Vampiric Touch* has a *range* of Self, but the *target* also includes any creatures you touch, not just you:

> Make a melee spell attack against a creature within your reach. On a hit, *the target* takes 3d6 necrotic damage, and you regain hit points equal to half the amount of necrotic damage dealt.

The spell does not target *only* you, so it's not eligible to be shared with your steed.

As a rule, if the spell, by any means:

1. Grants you a special (typically spell) attack (e.g. *Vampiric Touch*)
2. Includes an attack (e.g. *Booming Blade*)
3. Triggers a saving throw targeting anyone else

then it's not a spell targeting "only you", because the spell itself is responsible for that attack or save. Conveniently, this means you *never* need to worry about the attack roll or save DC the steed should use; if the spell allows for an attack/triggers a save, the steed can't use it.

If the Range entry alone defined something as "targeting only you", your mount could make Wishes when you do, and I'm fairly sure no DM is going to let you use your mount to make consequence-free Wishes.

Comment: What about spells that targets only the caster but affect an/or damage other creatures without any attack roll nor triggering any saving throw?

Comment: @Eddymage: I'd need examples. The rule I give says when a spell *definitely* targets someone else, but it's not exhaustive; there could be other cases where it targets others without involving a granted/included attack or save. I gave sufficient conditions, not necessary ones. I can definitely see some protective spells with reactive damage like Armor of Agathys being sharable, even though it can cause damage to attacking enemies; the enemies aren't *targeted* by the spell, they just get cold cause they insisted on hitting you while you were covered in ice.

Comment: I suppose saving throws triggered entirely passively in the same manner as Armor of Agathys's damage (don't know any off-hand, but I'm sure some exist) might also make the spell not count as targeting the saving individual. When the concept of targeting is not spelled out very well, you need DM judgment.

Comment: That's exactly one of the spells I was thinking about. I agree that this kind of spell needs dm's judgment, such as fireball wording, imho.