# Metamagic: Twinned spell aoe with one primary target?

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, metamagic

Twinned spell states "When you cast a spell that targets only one creature."

Since some spells, such as ice shard, target one creature, but afterwards do damage to nearby creatures, can you still use twinned spell?

Comment: To give some feedback on the downvotes here, a quick search on this site of twinned spell related questions should have easily resolved this question for you. We have *numerous* questions about twinned spell that all have the same answer - “To be eligible, a spell must be incapable of targeting more than one creature at the spell’s current level.”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### This is answered in the next paragraph

If you continue reading, the feature says:

> To be eligible, a spell must be incapable of targeting more than one creature at the spell’s current level.

Since *ice shard* is capable of targeting more than one creature (with the AOE), it is not eligible for Twinned Spell Metamagic.

Comment: But, as it says: "You create a shard of ice and fling it at one creature within range. Make a ranged spell attack against THE target" implying that it is only a single target. "THE target and each creature within 5 feet of the point where the ice exploded must succeed on a Dexterity saving throw or take 2d6 cold damage." so, twice it says that it is a single target.

Comment: @dndndndndnndndndnd [Victims of AoE spells are rather unambiguously referred to a targets numerous times throughout the rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/180665/62294).

Comment: You can read the discourse on this question for more details on what a target is: [What counts as a target for a spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/152115/41726)