# Can you cast Ashardalon’s Stride while mounted?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting, mount

The description of [Ashardalon’s Stride](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/ashardalons-stride) spell reports:

> 3rd level transmutation
>
> Range: Self
>
> Components: Verbal, Somatic
>
> Duration: Concentration, up to 1 minute
>
> The billowing flames of a dragon blast from your feet, granting you explosive speed. For the duration, your speed increases by 20 feet and moving does not provoke opportunity attacks. When you move within 5 feet of a creature or object that isn’t being worn or carried, it takes 1d6 fire damage from your trail of heat. A creature or object can only take this damage once during a turn.

My question is, how does this work when you’re mounted? Does the horse gain the twenty feet of movement, and it just carries you along with it? Do you have to dismount to use it? Do you shoot off your horse because of the explosive force of the spell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The horse does not gain anything from the spell.

The spell has a range of self: this means that it targets you and only you, no others. Indeed, from the PHB we can read in the [Range](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/spellcasting#Range) section (emphasis mine):

> Other spells, such as the *shield* spell, affect only you. **These spells have a range of self.**

Moreover, the spell description clearly states that all the effects apply to you, the caster.

#### This works if your mount has been created by the Find Steed spell.

The [*Find Steed*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-steed) spell (or the higher level version [*Find Greater Steed*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-greater-steed)) allows the caster to conjure a steed, and a nice option provided by such spell is the following one:

> While mounted on your steed, you can make any spell you cast that targets only you also target your steed.

In this case, *Ashardalon's Stride* can target both you and the steed, giving them firing hooves, increasing their speed by 20 ft and all the other cool effects.

A DM could consider the creatures affected by the flames of the stride as *targets* of the spell too (see the discussion about [What counts as a target for a spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/152115/63061)): this interpretation does not allow the *Ashardalon's Stride* to be a valid spell to be used in conjunction with *Find Steed*.

If I were the DM I would allow it, even if the above interpretation is correct, because of resources spent (2 spell slots) by the player and because the scene would be *really* cool.

Comment: So then, if you are mounted and cast Ashardalon’s Stride, you have to dismount before it takes effect?

Comment: @DMofDoom The effects starts as soon as you finished casting, but for using those effects you have to dismount, because everything the spell allows you to do depends on *you* moving, not on *being transported*.

Comment: Id argue they Ashardalon’s stride targets other creatures, so doesn’t work with a found steed.

Comment: @ThomasMarkovisonStrike I see your point and I recall all the debate about what counts as  a target, but in this case it seems pretty straightforward to me that the sole target of the spell is the caster. I'll add the reference to that interpretation about targets.

Comment: [Here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/180665/62294) is where I first made the case.

Comment: Have you played with this spell in a game?

Comment: @NautArchisonstrike Which one?

Comment: Ashardalons stride

Comment: @NautArchisonstrike To be honest no, but does it matter?

Comment: For me? Yes. But only because I have found that spell  to be very overpowered. The idea of suggesting it might work with fine steed really makes me think that you  had never seen the spell on in use. That’s just a personal example of why it’s dangerous to recommend actions that you haven’t tried.

Comment: @NautArchisonstrike Is it? Just for 1d6 (once per turn) and under concentration constraint?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147355/discussion-between-eddymage-and-nautarch-is-on-strike).